NVMe M.2 Drive not showing partition in Computer Management
I just installed a new NVMe M.2 Drive (TeamGroup MP44L PCIe Gen4x4) in my PC, I have initialized it in Computer Management, but I am unable to see any partitions or available space for this drive (See attachment below).
edit1: I am able to see the drive in UEFI.
How can do to fix this?


Also, I checked the motherboard's specification, confirming that all 4 M.2 slots support PCIe 4x4 SSDs.

Is the drive detected within UEFI? Most motherboards disable specific M.2 NVMe slots when specific PCIe slots are used.  In other words you cannot use both if they share the same PCIe lane.  Please [edit] your question to include that specific information from your manual so a greater degree of analysis can be performed.

What options do you see available when you right-click on the disk in that view you have pictured?

The drive is there, but it has no medium (like an empty CD drive). Return the SSD and have it replaced.
